# onclick coding html css jquery to highlight 2 buttons

Tags: css

I want to change this coding

2

Basically I have 4 buttons 1  2  3  4
When I click 1 1 highlights
When I click 2 (the code above ) 2 highlights

What I want to do is when I click 2 In want 1 and 2 to highlight.

if I change the code using F12 to

2

when clicking 2 the number 3 highlights

Comment: <div id="APPRAISEE_RATING_-2" onclick="selectRating('APPRAISEE_RATING_', '2', 'EKP002551131', 'EKP002551129')" class="rating-scale-EKP002551129 rating2 rating">2</div>

Comment: share your HTML, css, jquery. edit your question

Comment: what you really want to do is read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".yellow", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="yellow">Click me </button>
<button class="yellow">Click me </button>
<button class="yellow">Click me </button>
```